# What's difference between xhr.onload and xhr.onprogress

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

There are five events on an XMLHttpRequest instance.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onloadstart = res => {
    console.log('onloadstart')
}

xhr.onprogress = res => {
    console.log('onprogress')
}

xhr.onload = res => {
    console.log('onload')
}

xhr.onloadend = res => {
    console.log('onloadend')
}

xhr.onreadystatechange = res => {
    console.log(xhr.readyState)
}
console.log(xhr.readyState)

xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/vuejs/vue/issues');
xhr.send();
```

this is result

```
/*
1   
onloadstart
2
3
onprogress
4
onload
onloadend 
*/
```

from the results, I can find what the order is when events handler are called.

But I was confused  what is the actually difference of those events? I know the  whatwg specification said that onlandstart mean progress has begun and onprogress mean in progress ....

But I don't got it. I had try this code in every event handlers.

```
console.log(res)
console.log(res.target.status)
var result = res.target.responseText
console.log(JSON.parse(result))
console.log(res.target.getAllResponseHeaders())
console.log(res.target.getResponseHeader('x-ratelimit-remaining'))
```

The results are exactly same.

So what the difference we can find inside javascript code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onprogress) also says:

> The XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.onprogress is the function called periodically with information when an XMLHttpRequest before success completely

`onload` is called when progress is 100%

also note that the `onprogress` function is called with an [`event` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onprogress#Example) that consists of

> **event.loaded**: the amount of data currently transfered.
>
> **event.total**: the total amount of data to be transferred.

Here's an example:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow')
xhr.onprogress = e => { console.log(`Loaded ${e.loaded} bytes`, e); }
xhr.send();
```

This won't work in a snippet (downloads 0 bytes), probably because of CORS. Try opening a new Google tab and pasting that code in the console.

[image]

btw, `event.total` will be 0 unless provided by the server

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 0):

this is my conslusion:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onloadstart = res => {
    console.log('onloadstart')
    console.log(`Loaded ${res.loaded} bytes`)
}

xhr.onprogress = res => {
    console.log('onprogress')
    console.log(`Loaded ${res.loaded} bytes`)
}

xhr.onload = res => {
    console.log('onload')
    console.log(`Loaded ${res.loaded} bytes`)
}

xhr.onloadend = res => {
    console.log('onloadend')
    console.log(`Loaded ${res.loaded} bytes`)
}
xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow');
xhr.send();
```

onprogress will be triggered when browser receiving HTTP response, it may triggered multiple times.

onload will be triggered when progression is successful,

but progression may be failed, then it will triggered onerror or ontimeout or onabord.

anyway, it will trigger onloadend finally.